# How to refer a variable name in getUser in twitteR R package?

Tags: r, twitter

I am using twitteR R package and I am struck at a place with variable name substitution. I tried searching but no luck.
Please suggest if you have any solution. I could have used getUser() but need to use lookupUsers since I have multiple values.

```
USERLIST <- "android"
userInfo <- lookupUsers(USERLIST)
userInfo$android$id
[1] "382267114"
```

Now I need a way to call the value in USERLIST in the last command but it is not working.

```
userInfo$USERLIST$id
userInfo$`USERLIST`$id
```

Let me know how to do the variable substitution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you got

```
USERLIST <- c("android", "StackOverflow")
userInfo <- lookupUsers(USERLIST)
```

Then you can iterate over your `userInfo` list and access the id value of each user object like this:

```
sapply(userInfo[USERLIST], function(x) x$id)
#       android StackOverflow 
#   "382267114"   "128700677"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is exactly what I was looking for.