# How to get number of twitter followers from a list of users with lookupuser() function

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to get the number of followers in twitter from some users that I already know. I'm using getuser() or lookupuser() but I don't get the info that I want.

I did a streamR to get info about some hashtag and then saved it in a .json file. Now I parsed it and one of the column that I see is "in_reply_to_screen_name", and I want to know the followers of those users.

I have done a subset to group all those name in a list, so I don't want to go one by one.
I don't know why but getuser() function return an error, with list or just trying one user. Error: could not find function "getuser"

So I use lookupuser(), which is the same package, and seems like working but doesn't return the info that I'm looking for.

> $notoliverbutler
>
> [1] "notoliverbutler"
>
> $OverTheMoonbat
>
> [1] "OverTheMoonbat"
>
> $OHenleyAlex
>
> [1] "OHenleyAlex"

Example of the code:

```
subs1<-subset(tweet, (!is.na(tweet[,6]))
sublist<- c(subs1$in_reply_to_screen_name)
userinfo<- lookupUsers(sublist)
userinfo
```

I appreciate some help.
Thanks in advance!

In this post they get the id, but I'm looking the number of followers: [How to refer a variable name in getUser in twitteR R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118531/how-to-refer-a-variable-name-in-getuser-in-twitter-r-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information should be in the `user` object from the `twitteR` package:

```
user <- getUser("realDonaldTrump")
class(user)
# [1] "user"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "twitteR"
user$followersCount
# [1] 30929590
str(user$toDataFrame())
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  17 variables:
#  $ description      : chr "45th President of the United States of America"
#  $ statusesCount    : num 34964
#  $ followersCount   : num 30929590
#  $ favoritesCount   : num 50
#  $ friendsCount     : num 45
#  $ url              : logi NA
#  $ name             : chr "Donald J. Trump"
#  $ created          : POSIXct, format: "2009-03-18 13:46:38"
#  $ protected        : logi FALSE
#  $ verified         : logi TRUE
#  $ screenName       : chr "realDonaldTrump"
#  $ location         : chr "Washington, DC"
#  $ lang             : chr "en"
#  $ id               : chr "25073877"
#  $ listedCount      : num 69993
#  $ followRequestSent: logi FALSE
#  $ profileImageUrl  : chr "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1980294624/DJT_Headshot_V2_normal.jpg"

users <- lookupUsers(c("IvankaTrump","realTrumpWomen"))
sapply(users, function(x) x$followersCount)
 # IvankaTrump realTrumpWomen 
 #     3828630            656
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! that's exactly what I was looking for.

Still I don't know why getuser() doesn't work for me but luckily lookupuser() it does.